# write string to file the same way as it's printed

Tags: python, string, file, printing

The question is not about backspace, I'm asking more general..
(Is backspace is the only difference between print and write?)

I'm printing a string the include `'\x08'` (move cursor back).
When I print this string I get the exact result that I want.
But when I try to write it to a file it's write it as `'\x08'`.
Is there any way to write to file exact string as it's printed.
I mean I know that I can run though the string and fix hit, but I'm asking more general if I want to write the exact way that print?

Comment: Is it just backspace you need to implement, or all terminal control sequences?

Comment: Now it's about backspace, but I want to know if it's possible to write exactly the same as print work.

Comment: You just need a parser that works the same way as print does (to the screen? You don't say).

Comment: @quamrana Do you know any parser that work like this?

Comment: See https://pypi.org/project/stransi/